# How do I POST XML data with curl

Tags: http, post, curl

I want to post XML data with cURL. I don't care about forms like said in [How do I make a post request with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl).

I want to post XML content to some webservice using cURL command line interface. Something like:

```
curl -H "text/xml" -d "<XmlContainer xmlns='sads'..." http://myapiurl.com/service.svc/
```

The above sample however cannot be processed by the service.

---

Reference example in C#:

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://myapiurl.com/service.svc/");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
using(Stream s = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        sw.Write(myXMLcontent);
}
using (Stream s = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it can't be processed by the service"? Is the service receiving it correctly? Is it being posted correctly? What does the service receive from your request?

Comment: The service doesn't recognize the request. I receive an internal error page. When using my C# example this doesn't happen. The posted data is the same.

Comment: What HTTP response code do you receive? 500?

Comment: My hunch is the data comes in "escaped" to the web service (like `%3C%3Fxml+version=%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%`) that's what I ran into in java anyway...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`-H "text/xml"` isn't a valid header. You need to provide the full header:

```
-H "Content-Type: text/xml"
```

Answer (score 28):

I prefer the following command-line options:

```
cat req.xml | curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d @- http://www.example.com
```

or

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d @req.xml http://www.example.com
```

or

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml'  -d '<XML>data</XML>' http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with inline data :-)

Comment: Where we can keep this @req.xml file? This is what i want to pass empty file<tsRequest>
</tsRequest>

Answer (score 9):

It is simpler to use a file (`req.xml` in my case) with content you want to send -- like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @req.xml -X POST http://localhost/asdf`

You should consider using type 'application/xml', too (differences explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4832357/1773349))

Alternatively, without needing making curl actually read the file, you can use `cat` to spit the file into the stdout and make `curl` to read from stdout like this:

`cat req.xml | curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @- -X POST http://localhost/asdf`

Both examples should produce identical service output.

Comment: As a bonus, you don't need to specify `-X POST` with body data (because HTTP logic, obviously).  If you do, modern curls will warn `Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried url-encoding the data ? cURL can take care of that for you :

```
curl -H "Content-type: text/xml" --data-urlencode "<XmlContainer xmlns='sads'..." http://myapiurl.com/service.svc/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:

```
curl -v -X POST -d @payload.xml https://<API Path> -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8"
```