# Spring MVC: 415 (Unsupported Media Type) Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

It is somewhat recurring issue and I have found few solutions.But none of it work for me.

Trying to post a form with jQuery AJAX.

> Note: I posted it yesterday, thinking it is a client side issue. Tried
>   everything possible on client side but no luck.

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody public String handleSave(@RequestBody String formData)
    {


        System.out.println(formData);
}
```

**jQuery Request**(Tried everything what people suggested in comments)

It works fine if I send `data:$(this).serialize()` and `contentType:application/json`

```
$('form').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: collectFormData(),
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"text/xml"
                        },
                        dataType: 'xml;charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('data:'+data)
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('jqXHR:'+jqXHR+'\n'+'textStatus:'+'\n'+textStatus+'errorThrown:'+errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

**collectFormData()**

```
function collectFormData()
            {
                $rootElement = $.createElement($('form').attr('name'));
                $('form').find('div.section').each(function(index, section) {
                    var $sectionElement = $.createElement($(section).attr('name'));
                    console.log('Section Name is:'+$sectionElement);
                    $(section).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
                        var $fieldName  = $.createElement($(field).attr('name'));
                        $fieldName.text($(field).val());
                        $sectionElement.append($fieldName);
                    });
                    $rootElement.append($sectionElement);
                });
                console.log('Form XML is '+$rootElement.html());
                return $rootElement.html();                 
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="section" name="amount">
        <span class="section-title">Personal Information</span>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                Amount Of Insurance</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-amountOfInsurance" required="" id="123456" onblur="validateWithPRASE(this)">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                Customer First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-firstName" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                Customer Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-lastName" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                Middle intials</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-middleIntials" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
                Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" name="date">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                Street Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-address">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                City</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-city">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                State</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-state">
          </div>
          <div class="span6 form-inline">
                <label class="pocLabel">
                State 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount-state">
          </div>
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you add sample output of `collectFormData()` ?

Comment: What are you posting to? Does the server support XML POSTs?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I replaced `collectFormData()` to `<request></request>` but still same error.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am posting it to Spring MVC controller over Tomcat server. Yes server does support XML POSTs.

Comment: can you add `contentType: "text/xml",` instead of working with `headers` ?

Comment: try `application/xml`, maybe the receiver is too strict about it.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yeah. First tried with `contentType: text/xml`

Comment: @acdcjunior `contentType: "application/xml",` didn't help.

Comment: What is the target service implemented in? Do you have access to its code? Instead of trial an error through Ajax, I'd first get a hold of what the server accepts by sending something manually. Good tools for that are SoapUI or [REST Console for Chrome](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=REST+Console).

Comment: @acdcjunior You are absolutely right. I have already tried using the same tool. Got same error. Yes I do have access to server side code. But the same code is accepting JSON request.

Comment: It may accept JSON requests, this does not necessarily mean it will accept XML. Maybe your server side code does not accept. A look at it may be helpful. Can you paste some of it?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller only accepts JSON. It will never consume a XML.Try making it consume both:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",
                method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"})
```

Comment: Of course, `application/xml` there can be `text/xml` or both (`consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"}`), but [I'd use application/xml](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/489), although there are [debates about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832357/whats-the-difference-between-text-xml-vs-application-xml-for-webservice-respons).

Comment: Now request reaches to Controller but after that I am getting `no conversion from text to application/xml` error from ajax request.

Comment: Try using: `dataType: 'xml'` and encoding your data `data: encodeURIComponent(collectFormData())`.

Comment: What about the controller side? Should I change it to `consumes={"application/json","xml"}`?

Comment: You shouldn't, `dataType` is not the MIME type, it is a specific jQuery property.

Comment: Now I am getting ` "xml" does not contain '/'` at server side.

Comment: How about using just `encodeURIComponent()` (and leaving `dataType` as it was)?

Comment: I tried that before then xml's `<` and `>` are getting replaced by characters.

Comment: Add `collectFormData()`'s code to the question. I'll try to reproduce this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34637/discussion-between-himanshu-yadav-and-acdcjunior)

Answer (score 0):

I think `charset` should be defined in `contentType` instead of `dataType`, like this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: collectFormData(),
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('data:'+data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('jqXHR:'+jqXHR+'\n'+'textStatus:'+'\n'+textStatus+'errorThrown:'+errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also verify that your XML data starts with version and encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Can you also start your xml data with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` ?

Comment: Updated like this but same error.
`data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request></request>',
                        dataType: 'xml',
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Then I think you should check your server :) Or if you can make valid XML request with an other client, use WireShark to capture and compare network traffic.