# Issues with OnCFCRequest Method Functionality as my understanding

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee

This example does not work properly, when i pass the filters argument to a separate function to use it for searching

like this

> invalid call of the function Search, 4th Argument (filters) is of invalid type, can't cast String [{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"errorid","op":"eq","data":"1"},{"field":"line","op":"eq","data":...] to a value of type [struct]

I call it like this:

```
#SearchOptions(arguments.filters)#
```

from a function

```
<cfset filters = {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"template","op":"eq","data":"a"},{"field":"error_type","op":"eq","data":""}]}>

<cfdump var="#filters#">
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(filters.rules)#" index="i">
        #i#
        <cfset dataArr = filters.rules[i]>
        <cfloop collection="#dataArr#" item="key">
            #key#   
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>   
</cfoutput>
```

I had a onCFCRequest Function in my Application

```
<cffunction name="onCFCRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="I process the user's CFC request.">
    <cfargument name="component" type="string" required="true" hint="I am the component requested by the user." />
    <cfargument name="methodName" type="string" required="true" hint="I am the method requested by the user." />
    <cfargument name="methodArguments" type="struct" required="true" hint="I am the argument collection sent by the user." />
    <cfif !structKeyExists( application.apiCache, arguments.component )>
        <cfset application.apiCache[ arguments.component ] = createObject( "component", arguments.component ).init() />
    </cfif>
    <cfset local.cfc = application.apiCache[ arguments.component ] />
    <cfinvoke returnvariable="local.result" component="#local.cfc#" method="#arguments.methodName#" argumentcollection="#arguments.methodArguments#" />
    <cfset local.responseData = "" />
    <cfset local.responseMimeType = "text/plain" />
    <cfif structKeyExists( local, "result" )>
        <cfparam name="url.returnFormat" type="string" default="#getMetaData( local.cfc[ arguments.methodName ] ).returnFormat#" />
        <cfif ( (url.returnFormat eq "json") && !structKeyExists( url, "callback" ) )>
            <cfset local.responseData = serializeJSON( local.result ) />
            <cfset local.responseMimeType = "text/x-json" />
        <cfelseif ( (url.returnFormat eq "json") && structKeyExists( url, "callback" ) )>
            <cfset local.responseData = ( "#url.callback#(" & serializeJSON( local.result ) & ");" ) />
            <cfset local.responseMimeType = "text/javascript" />
        <cfelseif (url.returnFormat eq "wddx")>
            <cfwddx action="cfml2wddx" input="#local.result#" output="local.responseData" />
            <cfset local.responseMimeType = "text/xml" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset local.responseData = local.result />
            <cfset local.responseMimeType = "text/plain" />
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfset local.binaryResponse = toBinary( toBase64( local.responseData ) ) />
    <cfheader name="content-length" value="#arrayLen( local.binaryResponse )#" />
    <cfcontent type="#local.responseMimeType#" variable="#local.binaryResponse#" />
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recognize this pattern from a Ben Nadel [blog](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1647-learning-coldfusion-9-application-cfc-oncfcrequest-event-handler-for-cfc-requests.htm). The code you post in your question is missing two important parts. Firstly, the method that is called by `cfinvoke` from your  `application.apiCache` object - the call to this method fails and the exception is thrown. And secondly the JavaScript code that calls this method.

The error, actually, has a simple cause. Your JavaScript code likely passes the data as a string, when you pass ot a JavaScript object. Either because you call `JSON.stringify` or because some "magic" of a library you use serializes the object to a string.

The solution is to call `DeserializeJSON` on the fourth argument (named filters accoriding to the error message) of your ColdFusion function. I use code like the following myself. `bSave` only becomes `true` if the argument could be converted to a struct successfully.

When you have `cfargument` tags in the function, you have to change the `type` attribute of the one in question to `string`, accordingly.

```
<cfset local.struVals = {}>
<cfset local.bSave = false>

<cftry>
  <cfset local.struVals = DeserializeJSON( Arguments.filters )>

  <cfset local.bSave = true>

  <cfcatch></cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfif local.bSave>

</cfif>
```

Comment: There's an older post dealing with this pattern. Maybe you find some inspiration, there, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799587/coldfusion-oncfcrequest-changing-return-type-of-xml-into-wddx