# Error 415 Unsupported Media Type while executing list REST API from post man

Tags: postman

I am using List REST API for loading Party data. Using the details below:

```
Request type : POST
URL : http://localhost:1512/rest/V1.0/list/Party
Authorization : Yes
Header : No Header information
Body : form Data ->xml file.
```

When I send request I am getting below error. Can you please help me.

```
http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
Error 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case for PUT call, I set Body to "raw" and added "Content-Type" to "application/json"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You will need to include a header in your post request. Add a value under headers in Postman to include a key for `Content-Type` with a value of `application/xml`. You may also want to try a value of `text/xml` depending on what your body content is.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832357/whats-the-difference-between-text-xml-vs-application-xml-for-webservice-respons) for info on the difference between text/xml and application/xml.

Comment: There is no need to add a content-type header manually. You are overriding the value set by Postman. Just select form-data in POST request and send your request to see if it works.

Comment: @jHova is right, in some cases you need to add headers manually in postman to execute a POST request. Selecting the POST from the dropdown is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating a Web API 2.1 project in VS 2017 and I got the same problem. I just should disable SSL. The route to disable is right click on name project > properties > Debug > Anable SSL.

[image]