# Why do browsers omit XML tags?

Tags: flask, lxml, python-3.6

(Better title, anyone?) Rendering some XML made with `lxml.builder` using a small Flask app in Python 3.6. The function `makeXML` in module `mkX` builds and returns the XML like so:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
...
def makeXML():
    ...
    # myxml is type <class 'lxml.etree._Element'>
    f = ET.tostring(myxml, method='xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
    return f
```

Where `method=xml` could be omitted, as it's the default. The Flask app does:

```
@app.route('/getXML')
def getXML():
    xml = mkX.makeXML()    
    print(type(xml)) # xml is type <class 'bytes'>
    return xml
```

When I go to `[myurl]/getXML` in Chrome or Firefox, I see this:

```
eggs bacon sausage spam
```

It omits the XML tags. Why does that happen? Hitting view source, I see this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<someXML>
  <reclist>
    <dat>eggs</dat>
    <dat>bacon</dat>
    <dat>sausage</dat>
    <dat>spam</dat>
  </reclist>
</someXML>
```

With `pretty_print=True` it's nicely formatted. Without it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<someXML><reclist><dat>eggs</dat><dat>bacon</dat><dat>sausage</dat><dat>spam</dat></reclist></someXML>
```

Looking at other webservices that return XML, the browser does not omit the XML tags, for example [this one](http://service.aat-ned.nl/api/wwwopac.ashx?database=aat-gateway&search=term[nl-NL]=%22fiets*%22%20sort%20term[nl-NL]&limit=1).

Does this mean that myxml isn't valid XML? If so, what's the difference & how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser renders HTML, not XML. Most browser try to show what's possible from a document. In your case they show you all text nodes but not the XML elements that have no meaning in HTML.

Check if the HTTP response includes a line saying

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Only if this is set can the browser decide to display the XML document.

As you can see when you open the source view, the XML is complete. Everything works as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, in addition to Lutz Horn's answer, this is how to set Flask to return a specific mimetype:

```
...
from flask import Response
...
def getXML():
    xml = mkX.makeXML()    
    return Response(xml, mimetype='application/xml')
```

Since the xml is records rather than text, 'application/xml' is preferable over 'text/xml', more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832357/whats-the-difference-between-text-xml-vs-application-xml-for-webservice-respons).