# How to return a .xml file in a Laravel Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sitemap

I have generated a site map .xml file and want to return. I placed the file in my views folder and made this route:

```
Route::get('/site-map', function(){
    return view('sitemap.xml');
});
```

Although I just cant get it to display.

Answer (score 28):

By default Laravel doesn't support loading `.xml` files as views. That being said, there are several solutions to your problem:

- The easiest is to simply place your `sitemap.xml` in the `/public` directory. The browser will be able to see the file at `http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml`.
- You could load the contents of your file and return a response, setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/xml` or `text/xml` to tell the browser that the file you're serving is in fact an XML document.

  ```
  return response(file_get_contents(resource_path('sitemap.xml')), 200, [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
  ]);
  ```
- Alternatively, you could tell Laravel's view finder to support the `.xml` extension by doing something like this in a service provider (such as the `register` method of your `AppServiceProvider`, located at `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`):

  ```
  app('view.finder')->addExtension('xml');
  ```

  Once you've done that, Laravel should recognise `.xml` as a valid view extension and load your XML file as if it was a view. This has the added benefit of being able to pass data to it and use Blade/PHP within your view, if you want to:

  ```
  return view('sitemap');
  ```

Comment: You could you 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml' also, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832418/2428101