# What is the difference between mime type "application/css" and "text/css"?

Tags: html, css, mime-types

While serving files , the browser could not properly load when i sent mime type 
as "application/css" but works fine when i send "text/css". I cannot figure out why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'application/css' is not an officially assigned MIME type, while 'text/css' is (see [IANA list of assigned media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)). Do not expect user agents to process unofficial MIME types just because they 'look like' the same as official ones and humans would deduce the intent.

A similar dichotomy exists for the (main) xml mime type. The difference centers around 'readable/unreadable by a casual user' according to [this (admittedly ancient) SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832418/) which in turn cites [RFC 3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023) (now obsoleted by [RFC 7303](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7303)). This reason may not apply to '*/css' but may give an idea why browsers behave picky in this regard.