# XML in web browser, even without .xml extension

Tags: xml, browser

I have an application that serves a page of XML (if "page" is even the right term). For example, the page source might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

I would like to be able to open a web browser and view the page as XML (with collapsible tree, recognition of invalid XML, etc), which web browsers generally do. However it seems that without a `.xml` extension at the end of the URL path, the browsers are unwilling to do this. In spite of the xml declaration at the top line.

Is there anything I can do at the server level to make it work the way I'd like?

Comment: Firefox is able to open an xml file without extension as XML. Use web developer console to inspect the tree. The server should send `Content-Type
 application/xml` header or equivalent

Comment: @LMC Do you mean something more than the DOM inspector? I don't want to see the artificial DOM elements the browser creates, nor whatever patching it tries to do to broken XML.

Comment: Also I would like a solution that does not ask a user to use the developer console, if possible. I suspect that I may be out of luck. But I'm hoping there is a way to make it so the browser just shows the xml tree, like for example here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml.

Comment: The server should send `Content-Type  application/xml` header or equivalent

Comment: @LMC Thanks, that is the push that I needed. If you post as an answer, I can mark it accepted. It really does answer the question I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should send `Content-Type: application/xml` header or equivalent.
`text/xml` should also work.

For differences between the 2 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832418/2834978).